# React Js, refactor my redirect methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple components where i check if user is auth to redirect on login page

```
componentWillReceiveProps({auth}) {
    if (auth) {
      this.props.history.push('/login') 
    }
  }
```

I have copy this code ten times, there is a best way to do that ? I want to refactor do you have solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the layout of your app. Do the "multiple components" have a common parent or ancestor? If so, just have that one component check auth. You should have it only render components that depend on auth after the user has been authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommendation for cross-cutting concerns such as this is to use [higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

HOCs allow you to wrap your existing component so you can intercept `props` and apply higher-order logic such as authentication or logging or whatever and then pass the props down to the wrapped component when the HOC has done its work.

A rough example could be:

```
function withAuth(WrappedComponent) {
    return class extends React.Component {

     componentWillReceiveProps({ auth }) {
        if (auth) {
           // redirect
        }
      }
      render() {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      }
    };
  }
```

Usage would be:

```
const Hoc = withAuth(MyExistingComponent);
...
render() {
    return <Hoc {...props} />
}
```

A base class is an alternative but would quickly lose focus and become a dump for general shared logic. I think HOC is cleaner.

Comment: hey dashton, i think it's better to do:  export default withAuth(MyExistingComponent);  ?